# How can children who are not elect be a gift from God?

Tags: predestination

How can children who are not elect be a gift from God?
Scripture tells us that children are a gift from the Lord, the fruit of the womb a reward.
When a parent has surrendered "birth control" to God and He blesses with twelve gifts, most of whom don't appear to follow Him whole-heartedly, that causes more sorrow that the gift of the child.
I have spent the last 36 years birthing, nursing, homeschooling...pouring my life into the gifts God has given me and my husband. Only two of our children seem to be genuinely seeking God's ways.  It is heart-breaking!
How is a child destined for hell a gift?  Honestly it would have been better to not have those sweet, precious children than to see them reject God.

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site. Your question is way too important to be talking to strangers on the internet, so please talk to a trusted spiritual adviser (your minister, priest, or an old Christian friend.) But as much as it hurts to have family members who have rejected God, never assume that you can know their hearts or their futures, to know whether or not they are chosen by God. At the right time God will bring all his people to himself. Our role isn't to label people "elect" or "non-elect" but to keep sharing God's love with everyone we know.

Comment: Thanks be to the Lord, for the two of your children who are seeking him. This is good to hear.